# Где посмотреть исходные файлы стандартной библиотеки Си (Не C++) для Windows (не GNU/Linux)

Tags: c, компилятор, std, libc

В попытках разобраться с реализацией fopen() в Windows (Си) решил найти где-нибудь исходники этой функции. Проблема в том что перерыв весь интернет я обнаружил исходники "fopen.c" только для Unix систем, и как я понял это была просто надстройка над функцией open(), которая использует системные вызовы Linux. Так же в Windows Kits я нашел "fopen.cpp", который тоже не совсем то, т.к является реализацией для плюсов. На сайте Microsoft про функцию fopen написано только то, что она возвращает, какие аргументы принимает, исключения и т.д, но не исходный код.
Вопрос: Можно ли где-то посмотреть реализацию сишной функции fopen в Windows? (Я так понимаю, находится она в msvcrt.dll, но с ним особо ничего не сделаешь).

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146058/discussion-on-question-by-redis------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: fopen - это все-таки изначально сишная функция, а не GNU шная. MingGW вроде действительно использует msvcrt.dll, а Visual C/C++ по идее может еще и версионные использовать, типа msvcr100.dll.

Comment: @user7860670 Есть еще [виды MinGW](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/), которые используют `ucrtbase.dll`.